# What is the use of the second subscript of 2-D array, when it is passed to a function?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In *The C Programming Language*, they have said that only the first dimension (subscript) of an array is free to be specified; second subscript must be specified:

> If a two-dimensional array is to be passed to a function, the
>   parameter declaration in the function must include the number of
>   columns; the number of rows is irrelevant, since what is passed is, as
>   before, a pointer to an array of rows, where each row is an array of 5
>   `int`s. In this particular case, it is a pointer to objects that are
>   arrays of 5 `int`s. Thus if the array `daytab` is to be passed to a
>   function `f`, the declaration of `f` would be:
>
> ```
> f(int daytab[][5]) { ... }
> ```
>
> More generally, only the first dimension
>   (subscript) of an array is free; all the others have to be specified.

But in my programme, when I **change the value** of the second subscript (column), the programme still works the same.
For instance, the programme

```
#include"stdio.h"
void arf(int[][2]); // I wrote 2 instead of 5
main() {
    int a[][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {9,29,39,49,59}};
    arf(a);
}
void arf(int arr[][2]) {    //here too, changed the 2nd subscript
    size_t i;
    printf("%d", arr[0][4]);    //a[0][4] is 5
}
```

prints the output `5`, instead of a garbage value (my expectation).

Comment: The subscript 4 in the function is out of range, technically invoking UB.  In practice, while you use subscript 0 in the first index, you won't notice a problem.  If you printed `arr[1][4]`, you'd get one of the 9s printed.  Of course, it's hard to distinguish which of the 9s; you need to devise better test data (`0,9,8,7,6` as an initializer, for example; you should then see the only 9 as the output).  If you study the memory layouts you're telling the compiler about, you should get to understand why.  It you had the correct second dimension, `arr[1][4]` would be the `6` with my initializer.

Comment: You should also learn to write C11 (or, at least, C99) code and not archaic C90 code.  The return type should always be specified; the implicit `int` return type has been invalid in Standard C for all of the current millennium.  `int main(void)` is preferred; `int main()` has precedents in the standard; plain `main()` is invalid in current and old standard C (but not in archaic standard C, or pre-standard C, but you should not be using either of those).

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of casting a multidimensional array to another array the same size but with different geometry is not undefined: the standard guarantees that the elements of a multidimensional array will be laid out contiguously, in row-major order.

If you want to get the compiler to change the geometry of the array, you can cast to a pointer of the desired dimensions and then dereference, as in:

```
extern void f(int daytab[][5]);

int main(void)
{
  int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6  };
  f(*(int (*const)[2][5])a);
}
```

The use of the other subscript, i.e. casting to an array of dimensions `[5][2]` (or `[sizeof(a)/sizeof(int[2])][2]` for a bit more resiliency) is to tell the compiler how many rows there are, so it can potentially catch bounds errors at compile time.  In this specific example, where the information is just thrown away on the receiving end, that would not do you any good, but C also lets you declare a function prototype like `void arf( const ptrdiff_t m, const ptrdiff_t n, const int a[m][n])`.  C++ does not, but still lets you declare `void arf(const int a[rows][cols])`, where `rows` and `cols` are `constexpr` values.

Note that you should always, *always*, ***always*** check your array bounds for overflows in C and C++.

Comment: I think that he ment undefined behavior when accessing not laying arrays.

Comment: I may have misunderstood which behavior he meant. I’ll reword.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in two minds about whether it's advisable to discuss what is ultimately undefined behaviour.  Here's a minimally modified version of the code in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arf(int arr[][2]);

int main(void)
{
    int a[][5] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 0, 9, 8, 7, 6 } };
    arf(a);
}

void arf(int arr[][2])
{
    printf("%d\n", arr[0][4]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1][4]);
}
```

When compiled with GCC 7.3.0 on a Mac, I get:

```
$ gcc -o arr2d-13 arr2d-13.c
arr2d-13.c: In function ‘main’:
arr2d-13.c:8:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘arf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     arf(a);
         ^
arr2d-13.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int (*)[2]’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[5]’
 void arf(int arr[][2]);
      ^~~
$
```

That alone should be enough to tell you that you're doing it wrong.  I had to suppress my usual compilation flags; the code is not acceptable to me because it has that compiler warning.  However, when run, the output is:

```
5
9
```

Why?  Well, it is officially undefined behaviour, but …

The layout of the array in memory looks like:

```
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║ 5 ║ 0 ║ 9 ║ 8 ║ 7 ║ 6 ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

When, despite its warnings, the array is passed to `arf()`, the function thinks that row 0 of the input array starts with the element containing `1`, and row 1 of the input array starts with the element containing `3`, and so on — because you told the compiler that the function takes an array with 2 elements per row.

When you misuse subscript 4 (the declaration of the argument says that the valid second subscripts are `0` and `1`), then it adds 4 to the start address of the row, and ends up printing `5` in the first case; it prints `9` in the second case because the counting starts from the element containing 3 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 elements later is the `9`).

If your compiler wasn't warning you about the type mismatch, you need to get a better compiler.  If your compiler was warning you about the type mismatch, you need to pay attention to your compiler.  At this stage in your programming career, if the compiler deigns to warn you about your code, it has spotted a bug you need to fix.  I still regard compiler warnings like that — and I normally compile with options to enforce my rule (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes`) — but I've only been coding in C for nearly 35 years, so I know there's more for me to learn.

You also need to ensure you're compiling in C11 mode (the current standard), or in C99 (the old standard) — there is no real excuse for compiling in C90 (the archaic standard) or pre-standard modes.
C99 said `main()` on its own is outdated because there is no return type. Always specify the return type explicitly, preferably using `int main(void)` when you ignore the argument list, or `int main()` if you insist (there are examples in the standard that use that notation).

Comment: By 99 standard any function by default is returning an `int` isn't it?

Comment: No; you must explicitly state the return type of every function in C99.  See [C11 Forward ¶7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp7) — • _remove implicit int_ … • _remove implicit function declaration_ (That paragraph summarizes the changes in C99.)

Comment: Thanks, sir, this helped a lot.
I am using Windows' Code::Blocks v17, GCC 4.9 (Latest for C::B).
Would you suggest any better IDE that _**builds**_ the code fast?

Comment: I don't have any views on IDEs that are worth mentioning.  I don't use one.